# JS autocomplete package in ST3 annoying autocomplete list at the end of the line after semicolon

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

I have some annoying issue with my ST3 JavaScript Completions package. So, whenever I hit space even If I haven't write anything yet I get JS autocomplete list with bunch of different functions and every time when I want to go to the next line I can't because there is that autocomplete list and I need to click esc button first to remove that list and than click enter so I can move on to the next line. It is pretty annoying when code is a bit longer, every time at the end of the line I need to click esc and than enter.

I don't want to remove that plugin, it's quite useful but I haven't this problem until today. I tried to reinstall that package but I still have the same problem.

Is there any way to fix it? I don't want It to show every time just e.g. when I start typing the name of some functions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you visit the package's [page on Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Completions), you'll see that the package was just updated 2 days ago. I would suggest that you [file an issue](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/JavaScript-Completions/issues) and explain in detail exactly what you are seeing, with images to demonstrate the behavior. The author of the package is much more able to address this issue than we are.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you, I didn't find It on github before. I'll ask there.