# Prevent sublime autocompleter popup after semicolon(;) at the end of line

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, sublimetext

[image]

After `;`, i.e at the end of each line when I press enter , I get word 'prototype' is added() by the auto completer.I i press shift+enter then acts as normal enter without any autocomplete. added. How can I stop auto-completion after a semi-colon?

and this is the list of packages I have installed.I think its a problem related to some package.

[image]

If any of these packages causing problem plz help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS autocomplete package in ST3 annoying autocomplete list at the end of the line after semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546050/js-autocomplete-package-in-st3-annoying-autocomplete-list-at-the-end-of-the-line)

Comment: Its not exactly the copy of that question by the way. In that case when the package was reinstalled or uninstalled it was not giving any effect to the issue.. But in my case i tried to change the packages and the issue is not there any more..

Comment: that question was particularly about the package 'JavaScript Completions'.. but in my case i was not able to figure out which package was causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer of my question.. I am posting this so that it may help someone out. its because of the package 'Auto Complete JavaScript with Method Signature '. when i disabled the package these autocomplete extensions were gone.

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your settings:

```json
  "auto_complete_selector": "meta.tag, source - comment - string.quoted.double.block - string.quoted.single.block - string.unquoted.heredoc - punctuation.terminator - punctuation.separator"
```

This will prevent the autocomplete suggestion pop-up from appearing after typing semicolons or other statement terminators, or separators such as commas and colons.

Relevant documentation:

- https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/completions.html#settings
- https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/scope_naming.html#punctuation
- https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selectors.html

Comment: doesnt works with `)` or `}` :'(

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking, my problem was the package 'SublimeCodeIntel'.

It was adding `$('string/element/array/function/jQuery object/string, context')` to the end of every line, after typing a semicolon (the autocomplete suggestion was `$('#select DOM Element')`).